# Cant find prefix Header Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I'm running into an issue with Xcode 6 where Xcode can't find the path to my Prefix header file. I've followed other posts online and can't seem to resolve such a simple issue. I didn't have a prefix header in my project so I created one calling it MyProject-Prefix.pch. I added this file into my project structure

I then go into project -> build settings -> APPLE LLVM 6.0 Language -> Prefix header.

I set the value for Prefix Header to:

```
$(SRCROOT)/MyProject-prefix.pch
```

However when I clean and build the project I get an error:

**clang: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/me/my-ios-app/MyProject/MyProject-prefix.pch'
clang: error: no input files**

Can anyone help me configure this properly or point out what I'm missing?

Comment: Where is your prefix header located?

Comment: Right in the main project directory. Its not in any subfolder or anything like that.

Comment: So it is at the path specified in the error message?

Comment: Yes that is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Xcode searches prefix header file from the folder where the `xcodeproj` or `xcworkspace` file is located, so you should specify it just

```
MyProject-prefix.pch
```